# Can I create a SQL database in Visual Studio Code for OS X?

Tags: sql, macos, visual-studio-code

I have just downloaded Visual Studio Code (for OS X) and I wanted to try and create a simple REST API server to test out all possibilities. I can't seem to find how to create a SQL database.

Do I need to create one in another application? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is not a fully featured IDE like Visual Studio. It does not support tasks such as creating databases or viewing them from within the App. If you want create a database, refer to the docs of the database provider for your target platform.

As for the REST API server, Visual Studio Code can be great help - specially if you are using ASP.Net 5 or node.

Comment: Yeah ASP.Net it's the goal to run it on a windows host, so I'm glad I can develop on the road with my MacBook.

Comment: what about mongodb? mongodb has a mac version... can i use the mongodb csharpdriver from nuget in visual studio code so i can access the mongodb in mac?